# Condition on AWS credentials to by used only by some arn or my aws account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-sts

[image]

I am using a setup like this. Basically authorizer lambda assumes a role and passes credentials to the API handler. The API handler uses these credentials to request other AWS services and the API handler lambda doesn't have any role to itself. How can I add conditions in the IAM role so only the API handler can use the credentials?

Comment: I don't think you can do that because the credentials are valid for however has them. Your actual mission is to prevent others from having those credentials and to not scope them properly. This is generally not what the Authorizer is supposed to be used for (or are you not talking about https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html ? - the picture does not match it). Instead the API Handler should have its own role and its own permissions. *That* role can be configured to only be useable from that one single lambda function.

Comment: since my comment edit grace period is over: *"and to scope them"* (without the 'not'), *"(are you"* (without the 'or')

Comment: @luk2302 https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/building-a-multi-tenant-saas-solution-using-aws-serverless-services/ I am trying to implement this. Please check figure 6

Comment: A, multi tenant stuff - Okay, point 1 still remains true though: the credentials are valid for whoever has them.